# Why is IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup throwing an exception when run on SPSite.RootWeb?

Tags: spcontext, spsite, membership, exception

Running this code in PowerShell (or even in a web context in C#) gives an unexpected behavior:

[image]

Calling `IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup` directly on the `RootWeb` object gives an exception, and worse: it messes up the `SPSite` object. In a web context where the SPSite object is the `SPContext.Current.Site` object, this is fatal for the entire application, as the SPContext SPSite is wonky for the remaining time of the current request.

If we were to call `SPSite.RootWeb` first, everything works fine. Why?

Answer (score 1):

When you run `IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup` directly, the `SPWeb` object has not been internally initialized yet and via PowerShell you don't have web request object either which it often use internally.

One can argue that the SPWeb object should check if it has been initialized in this particular case, but it is what it is.

By calling for example the `Title` property the object is initialized and the call works.

```
$site = get-spsite http://somesite
$site.Title # trigger init
$site.IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(2274)
```